# Variable destructuring in Nunjucks template

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, nunjucks

Currently variables are referred as properties inside `for` loop:

```
{% id, item in items %}
  <div>
    {{ id }}
    {{ item.foo }}
    {{ item.bar }}
    {{ item.baz }}
    ...
```

It is desirable to skip `item.` part in `for`:

```
  ...
  <div>
    {{ id }}
    {{ foo }}
    {{ bar }}
    {{ baz }}
```

Similarly to ES6 destructuring:

```
for (const [id, {foo, bar, baz}] of Object.entries(items)) ...
```

Is it possible to refer them as variables and not `item` properties in Nunjucks template?

Comment: Did you try `{% id, {foo, bar, baz} in items %}`?

Comment: @Bergi Haven't found anything like that in the docs. And sadly, yes, I've tried this, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho, it's behavior is danger. `Foo` and `Bar` can override passed to template and `{% set Foo = ... %}` vars.

```
var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
var env = nunjucks.configure();

env.addGlobal('destruct', function(obj) { 
    for (var key in obj)
        this.ctx[key] = obj[key];
})

var res = nunjucks.renderString(`
    {% for id, item in items %}
        {{destruct(item)}}
        {{id}} - {{foo}} - {{bar}}
    {% endfor %}
    `,
    {
        items: {
            A: {id: 10, foo: 'fooA', bar: 'barA'}, 
            B: {id: 20, foo: 'fooB', bar: 'barB'}
        }
    }
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I'm not totally aware of how Nunjucks work. It doesn't create a separate context inside `for`, does it? Sure, it can provide ill effects. Thanks for `destruct` idea, it looks like a good starter, it likely should accept a list of destuctured props too.

Comment: Nunjucks don't create separate context even for `id` (but not `item`). `id` defines after for.